# Reading and writing to the same csv file after comparing two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.7

I have two files that I want to compare, I have the for loop to compare them, but I'm unsure of how to continue and make it so that I have data for each line of the first file that met the conditions of the if/else statement.

```
date_location = 3
numeric_location = 4


with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    next(f1)
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as f2:
        next(f2)
        for i in (f1):
                f1_date = (i.split(',')[date_location])
                f1_number = (i.split(',')[numeric_location])
                for j in (f2):
                        f2_date = (j.split(',')[date_location])
                        f2_number = (j.split(',')[numeric_location])
                        if f1_date == f2_date:
                            if f2_number > f1_number:
#                                print('WIN')
                                continue
                            elif f2_number <= f1_number:
#                                print('lose')
                f2.seek(0, 0)
```

This is the code that I currently have. What I want is to show the results of the if loop into `file1.csv`.Though I'm unable to make it record what I have printed into `file1.csv`. Is there any way for me to do this preferably in pandas? I tried earlier to make the for loop in pandas but it wouldn't allow me to do that with the dataframes for both files.

Comment: Usually we read a whole csv file into a data structure like a `DataFrame`, the do some work on it, and finally write a whole new file.  Remember, a csv file is just a text file, lines of columns.  You can add new lines to the end of the file, but you can't change or rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two Pandas DataFrame and use `np.where()` to get the comparison.

Assume you have 2 files, called `df1` and `df2`. There's a `score` column in each df. Then, you can make the comparison by

```
result = np.where(df1.score > df2.score, "WIN", "lose")
```

and the if you type result, it shows the comparison result.

You can use the following code to experiment on your side:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df2 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df3 = np.where(df1.A > df2.B, 'WIN', 'lose')
df3
```

Update:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df2 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df3=pd.DataFrame({})
for col in df2.A:
   df3[col] = np.where(df1.A < col, 1,0)
df3
```

Or this:

```
for i in df1.index: # go through file 1 
  r1 = df1.iloc[i] # each time choose a row
  df = df2[df2.D == r1.D] # and choose the rows to compare from file 2, if D matches  
  c = np.where(df.A <= r1.A, "Yes","No") 

  for a in c:
      print (a)
```

Comment: To read in a csv file as a Pandas dataframe, use `pd.read_csv('YOUR_FILE_LOCATION')`. In this case, `pd.read_csv('./file1.csv')`

Comment: I'm assuming this would only run until the shorter dataframe is exhausted though, is there a pandas equivalent to `.seek()`? since I'm trying to read all of the second file with each line of the first file

Comment: `[max(np.where(i > df2.A, 1, 0)) for i in df1.A]` will give you a binary array which shows if row `i` in `df.A` is bigger than any of number in `df2.A`

Comment: ```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df2 = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()

df3=pd.DataFrame({})
for col in df2.A:
    df3[col] = np.where(df1.A < col, 1,0)
df3
```